# Iterating Select By Location in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location

I need to do *exactly* what the help topic http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Select_By_Location_Select_based_on_spatial_relationship_within_the_layer/0017000000tr000000/ says can be done, but they do not include the model architecture:

> The Select Layer By Location tool allows the Input Feature Layer to be
>   the same the layer specified in theSelecting Features parameter. A
>   useful application of this behavior is to select adjacent, connected,
>   or nearby features within a layer. Different Relationship options can
>   be used to generate the desired analysis or result. For details of how
>   the Relationship options differ, see Select By Location: graphical
>   examples.
>
> A loop inside a script or the For or While iterators in ModelBuilder
>   can be used in conjunction with this approach to expand a selection
>   based on a number of iterations or until some criterion is met. **One
>   common criterion is expand until no new features are added to the
>   selection.** The Get Count tool can be used to establish when the
>   number of selected features stops changing (therefore stops growing).

Could someone show me how this type of model is put together?

I'm especially having trouble determining where I can put GetCount functions in the model to get numbers of selected features before and after each Select by Location, and also figuring out where to put a While iterator (if indeed that is the correct iterator to use) so that only the Select by Location process is repeated and not the entire model.

Comment: I don't know modelbuilder well, but I can give some pointers.  You will need to set it up in a variable, if/then/else check, and iterator.  Variable gets assigned (count or something), if/then/else checks for count = something, if it is continue, else hit the iterator and run your select by location and loop back to the if/then/else.  I am sure if you Google each of these concepts you'll come up with a process.  You may need to set up a temp layer to store selected features to be used as a layer in select by location.

Comment: I've googled my butt off, and I keep finding post lamenting the fact that there are no good examples, like:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41702/using-arcgis-modelbuilder-with-a-while-iterator

and 

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/using-while-iterator-in-modelbuilder

and

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63571


Again, I really just need to see the model structure for exactly what Esri describes in their help topic.

Comment: Figured it out finally.  Have to make a submodel that does the initial selection, then a submodel that does the select by location, set up your input and output parameters for each submodel correctly, and then hook them together.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it.  Include a screenshot or more detail if you could for others who may find this question while searching here.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out finally. Have to make a submodel that does the initial selection, then a submodel that does the select by location, set up your input and output parameters for each submodel correctly, and then hook them together.

[image: Full model]
[image: Sub-models]